# UNION operator to seperate the columns based on the flag value

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I have table as below.

```
Name    Primary phone   Primary Ind
Manju       11              Y
Manju       22              N
Tyagi       33              N
Tyagi       44              Y
```

And I want my result to be displayed like below based on the `Primary Ind` Flag in my table above. Basically if the primary indicator is "Y" Phone No should go to 'Primary Phone`. IF "N", it should go to "Non Primary"

```
Name    Primary Phone   Non Primary
manju        11               22
Tyagi        44               33
```

I need to achieve this using select and UNION. this is the assignment gave to me. Can somebody help how to do it?

Comment: who gave you this assignment ? A union is the last thing you need to solve this its even a bad idea to use a union for this

Comment: From what I tell of your sample data, it can be possible that Manju hase more than  2 phones and for example 3 non primary phones, how would your desired result look like than ?

Answer (score 3):

A self join

```
 select t1.name, t1.phone as primary, t2.phone as non 
   from table t1 
   join table t2 
     on t2.name = t1.name 
    and t1.ind = 'y' 
    and t2.ind = 'n'
```

Comment: I like your solution and the way I'd think to do it too, only thing is that I think this is a homework assignment that requires the use of `UNION` from the way its being described. Is that the case, @unnikrishnan?

Comment: @JohnBustos Not convinced giving student artificial constraints is a good thing.

Comment: Oh, agreed, just pointing out what was asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not the way I'd handle this but as it's the requirement:

Simply generate two sets of data one with Y one with N, union and get the max of each.  That max assumes that each record only has 2 phone #'s (one each primary & non-Primary)

```
SELECT name
     , max([Primary Phone]) as [Primary Phone]
     , max([non Primary] as [Non Primary)
FROM (SELECT name, [Primary phone], null as [non Primary]
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE [Primary Ind] = 'Y'

      UNION ALL

      SELECT name, Null as [Primary Phone], [Primary Phone ]
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE [Primary Ind] = 'N') DT
GROUP BY name
```

Union vs union all depends on if you have duplicates you need to eliminate, if you know you don't union all is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Union is not necessary but still you need it ,

```
select name,primaryphone,nonprimary from (
    select  name,primaryphone
    from 
    (
    select name,primaryphone,'primary' PrimaryInd from yourtable where primaryind='Y'
    union
    select name,primaryphone,'non primary' from yourtable where primaryind='N'
      ) a
      where primaryind='primary')a1 join 


     ( select  name as name1,primaryphone as nonprimary
    from 
    (
    select name,primaryphone,'primary' PrimaryInd from yourtable where primaryind='Y'
    union
    select name,primaryphone,'non primary' from yourtable where primaryind='N'
      ) a
      where primaryind='non primary')a2
     on a1.name=a2.name1
```

check this-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a8db/23